# Warning: validateDOMNesting(...): <li> cannot appear as a descendant of <li>

Tags: css, next.js

There are many similar problems, but I can't solve this background error warning. Strictly speaking, I'm still a novice. I know to change li, but I don't know where to start. Please help me. This error warning:

```
next-dev.js?3515:20 Warning: validateDOMNesting(...): <li> cannot appear as a descendant of <li>.
    at li
    at li
    at ul
    at div
    at div
    at Top (webpack-internal:///./components/header/Top.js:28:84)
    at header
    at Header (webpack-internal:///./components/header/index.js:18:11)
    at div
    at Home
    at PersistGate (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/redux-persist/es/integration/react.js:39:5)
    at Provider (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/react-redux/es/components/Provider.js:13:3)
    at MyApp (webpack-internal:///./pages/_app.js:22:11)
    at PathnameContextProviderAdapter (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/next/dist/shared/lib/router/adapters.js:62:11)
    at ErrorBoundary (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/@next/react-dev-overlay/dist/client.js:301:63)
    at ReactDevOverlay (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/@next/react-dev-overlay/dist/client.js:850:919)
    at Container (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/next/dist/client/index.js:62:1)
    at AppContainer (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/next/dist/client/index.js:172:11)
    at Root (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/next/dist/client/index.js:347:11)
```

I hope something can help me correct him. Like obsessive-compulsive disorder, I can't face the red color of the back. This is my original code:

```
import styles from "./styles.module.scss";
import { MdSecurity } from "react-icons/md";
import { BsSuitHeart } from "react-icons/bs";
import { RiAccountPinCircleLine, RiArrowDropDownFill } from "react-icons/ri";
import Link from "next/link";
import { useState } from "react";
import UserMenu from "./UserMenu";

export default function Top() {
  const [ loggedIn, setLoggedIn ]  = useState(true);
  const [visible, setVisible] = useState(false);
 
  
  return (
    <div className={styles.top}>
      <div className={styles.top_container}>
        <div></div>
        <ul className={styles.top_list}>
          <li className={styles.li}>
            <MdSecurity />
            <span>Buyer Prodtection</span>
          </li>
          <li className={styles.li}>
            <span>Customer Service</span>
          </li>
          <li className={styles.li}>
            <span>Help</span>
          </li>
          <li className={styles.li}>
            <BsSuitHeart />
            <Link href={"/profile/whishlist"}>
              <span>Whishlist</span>
            </Link>
          </li>
          <li
            className={styles.li}
            onMouseOver={() => setVisible(true)}
            onMouseLeave={() => setVisible(false)}
          >
            {loggedIn ? (
              <li className={styles.li}>
                <div className={styles.flex}>
                  <img
                    src={"/"}
                    width={22}
                    height={22}
                    alt=''
                  />
                  
                  <RiArrowDropDownFill />
                </div>
              </li>
            ) : (
              <li className={styles.li}>
                <div className={styles.flex}>
                  <RiAccountPinCircleLine />
                  <span>Account</span>
                  <RiArrowDropDownFill />
                </div>
              </li>
            )}
            {visible && <UserMenu loggedIn={loggedIn} />}
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot nest li tags in html.
For example

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <li></li>
  </li>
</ul>
```

If you would like a nested list, you can do this

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <ul>
      <li></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```